# is it possible to use bucket_script in java?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I read the [**Aggregations**](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-aggs.html) official documentation, it says

> Elasticsearch provides a full Java API to play with aggregations. See the Aggregations guide.

But I cannot just translate my following queries to Java code sadly.

- [bucket_script](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.6/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-script-aggregation.html)
- [bucket_sort](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.6/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-sort-aggregation.html)

```
{
  “size”: 0,
  “aggs”: {
    “mallBucket”: {
      “terms”: {
        “field”: “mallId”,
        “size”: 20,
        “min_doc_count”: 3,
        “shard_size”: 10000
      },
      “aggs”: {
        “totalOrderCount”: {
          “value_count”: {
            “field”: “orderSn”
          }
        },
        “filteredCoupon”: {
          “filter”: {
            “terms”: {
              “tags”: [
                “hello”,
                “cool”
              ]
            }
          },
          “aggs”: {
            “couponCount”: {
              “value_count”: {
                “field”: “orderSn”
              }
            }
          }
        },
        “countRatio”: {
          “bucket_script”: {
            “buckets_path”: {
              “orderCount”: “totalOrderCount”,
              “couponCount”: “filteredCoupon>couponCount”
            },
            “script”: “params.couponCount/params.orderCount”
          }
        },
        “ratio_bucket_sort”: {
          “bucket_sort”: {
            “sort”: [
              {
                “countRatio”: {
                  “order”: “desc”
                }
              }
            ],
            “size”: 20
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show what Java code you have so far? Here is the official documentation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-aggregation-builders.html#_pipeline_aggregations

Comment: @Val Thank you, I'm now checking this page now `PipelineAggregatorBuilders.bucketScript()`. I missed this page, so sad ;(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [official Java Client documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-aggregation-builders.html#_pipeline_aggregations), you can use the `PipelineAggregatorBuilders.bucketScript()` method to achieve what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help from @Val, I resolved this annoying issue as follows (*just for reference*).

```
        Map<String, String> pathMap = new HashMap<>();
        pathMap.put("orderCount", ES_AGGS_COUNT_ONE);
        pathMap.put("couponCount", String.format("%s>%s", ES_AGGS_FILTER_ONE, ES_AGGS_COUNT_TWO));
        AggregationBuilder aggregationBuilder = AggregationBuilders.terms(ES_BUCKETING).field(ES_FIELD_MALL_ID)
                .minDocCount(abnormalCouponHiveConsumingTask.getMinOrderCount()).shardSize(10_000).size(getTopCount(request))
                .subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.count(ES_AGGS_COUNT_ONE).field(ES_FIELD_ORDER_SN)).subAggregation(
                        AggregationBuilders.filter(ES_AGGS_FILTER_ONE, getTagFilter(request))
                                .subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.count(ES_AGGS_COUNT_TWO).field(ES_FIELD_ORDER_SN))
                                .subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.sum(ES_SUM_ONE).field(ES_FIELD_COUPON_AMOUNT)))
                .subAggregation(PipelineAggregatorBuilders
                        .bucketScript(ES_AGGS_SCRIPT, pathMap, new Script("params.couponCount/params.orderCount")))
                .subAggregation(PipelineAggregatorBuilders.bucketSort(ES_SORT,
                            Lists.newArrayList(new FieldSortBuilder(ES_AGGS_SCRIPT).order(SortOrder.DESC))).from(0)
                            .size(getTopCount(request)));
```

---

Along the way, I encountered another issue caused by the *low* version of ES client, and I upgraded to `7.4` and the `org.elasticsearch.common.ParsingException` solved.